# Postgres Query to get details before 2 months

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get the details of customers who has not visited for last two months by using `postgresql`. Below is my Query. I am getting all the data before 2months, but also wants to know whether the customer visits in between two months. If so, the result of query must not show that customer.

```
select usr.name,usr.mobile,ihv.create_date,ihv.partner_id from 
invoice_header_view ihv join user_store_mapper usm on ihv.partner_id = 
usm. partner_id join public.user usr on usr.user_id = usm.user_id 
where usm.store_id = '123' and cast(ihv.create_date as date) = 
cast(now() as date) -  interval '2 month' and (cast(ihv.create_date as 
date) between cast(ihv.create_date as date) and cast(now() as 
date) - interval '2 months')
```

Comment: the last part of your WHERE condition is always true, as in  `X BETWEEN X AND X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of ways to solve it is `NOT EXISTS`. You can create a corelated subquery which will check if there are any newer rows in `invoice_header_view`.

Another way is to use `GROUP BY`, like

```
SELECT
    usr.name, usr.mobile, ihv.partner_id,
    max(ihv.create_date) AS max_create_date,
    count(*) AS invoice_header_count
FROM invoice_header_view ihv 
    JOIN user_store_mapper usm ON ihv.partner_id = usm.partner_id
    JOIN public.user usr ON usr.user_id = usm.user_id
WHERE
    usm.store_id = '123'
    AND ihv.create_date >= now() - interval '2 months' 
GROUP BY
    1,2,3
HAVING
    max(ihv.create_date) <= now() - interval '2 months';
```

Comment: Suppose I had visited on 26/02/2017 and 26/03/2017. So when I queries for customers those who doesn't visit shops for last two months(from current day) , my name should not be there, because I had again visited the same shop on 26/03/2017 also. I need help to write the query to get the result in above form

Answer (score 0):

If you want customers whose most recent date is more than two months ago, then you can use:

```
SELECT u.name, u.mobile
FROM invoice_header_view ihv JOIN
     user_store_mapper usm
     ON ihv.partner_id = usm.partner_id JOIN
     public.user u
     ON u.user_id = usm.user_id
WHERE usm.store_id = 123   -- I'm guessing this really a number
GROUP BY u.name, u.mobile
HAVING max(ihv.create_date) <= curdate() - interval '2 months';
```

Comment: Suppose I had visited on 26/02/2017 and 26/03/2017. So when I queries for customers those who doesn't visit shops for last two months(from current day) , my name should not be there, because I had again visited the same shop on 26/03/2017 also. I need help to write the query to get the result in above form.